# One to many relationship - Code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I've got these two classes where I want to add a one to many relationship.

A monster has only one location
But
A location can have many monsters

But I get this error when I try to `Update-Database`

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Monsters_dbo.Locations_LocationId". The conflict occurred in database "Idle", table "dbo.Locations", column 'LocationId'.

**Monster**

```
public class Monster
{
    public Monster()
    {

    }

    public int MonsterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

**Location**

```
public class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        Monsters = new List<Monster>();
    }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Monster> Monsters { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing out existing data in your Location table ... Or make your FK nullable in your Monsters table.

Answer (score 0):

In your context you could use:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasMany(l => l.Monsters)
}
```